# Views using taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a simple Drupal 6 website with a content type 'Software' this has various CCK fields regarding evaluation of the software. The software has been evaluated by a speech therapist and the website is used by people suffering from Aphasia to help them pick the software that is right for them.

One of the pages on the site has a comparison table built using views, selecting nodes with their CCK fields.
http://www.aphasiasoftwarefinder.org/comparison-table

I appologise for the amature look of this site, I knew very little about theming and am still learning.

I am now re building this site in Drupal 7 and it has become much more complex with regard to the various evaluation criterion and is also including Apps and other software that may be useful to people. I decided to use Taxonomy instead of CCK fields as there about about 7 areas or evaluation (Taxonomy volcabulary) each with its own list of terms.

Everything is working well except when I come to creating a comparison table.
I want to be able to use the Taxonomy terms that are the same as the CCK evaluation fields from the Drupal 6 site but I am strugling as to how I can achieve this.
So I have a Taxonomy Volcabulary 'Evaluation' with a list of 8 or so terms, I want to be able to separate those terms out as columns along the top of the view and list the nodes down the side, then populate the colunms with a tick if they have that taxonomy term.

If someone could point me in the direction of any tutorials that may help towards this goal or come up with any ideas on how this could be done???

Many thanks
Julie

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Taxonomy : All Terms` to display the terms each node has associated with a single vocabulary. You would have to spend some time on styling them properly.